# Active Storage Unpermitted Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have a model called **Car** and have many attachments like this
**has_many_attached :images**. I am trying to upload multiple images but I keep getting **Unpermitted parameter: :images**. and I have already permitted it.

```rb
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end

# controller...

def new_car
  @car = Car.create(car_params)
  car_attributes = @car.attributes.except("updated_at", "created_at")

   app_response(message: "Car uploaded successfully", status: :created, data: {car: car_attributes})
end

private
def car_params
  params.permit(:model, :brand, :price, :year_of_manufacture, images: [])
end
```

I want to be able to upload multiple files. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: `params.require(:car).permit(:model, :brand, :price, :year_of_manufacture, images: [])`

Comment: How your params look?

Comment: Show your params how do they look like.